# How to change the regular expression for $word using Perl?

Tags: perl

In below I had showed you the part of the code where i struck to do  using perl regular expression.

Part of code where i struck with how to do:

```
if(-f $outfile)
        {
        $word=~s/("\S+|\S+|")\s*/$1/g; 

                print $fh_out '<a href="' .$word.'/'.$word. '.html">'.$word.'</a>';
        }   
        else
        {
            print "invalid";
        }
```

Consider only the $word part:

Here $word has the following contents:

```
DAC_Datapath
JESD_RX
Overall_DV
RNM_model
tv1
tv2
tv3
tv4
tv5
1
2
3
path
RX
Overall_DV
M_model
tv11
tv12
tv13
tv14
tv15
1
2
3
```

For your kind information:

here tv5 (i.e the digit 5 is bigger compared to other tv).So other rows remain to be same where ever tv range starts at that range it should compare with other tv and print the greatest one.Like wise after few more rows we will find tv11..tv15.At point it should print tv15.For your knowledge the other rows should not be affected while doing for tv*

I want to bring the `$word` into the following contents. How can I do it with regular expression?

Expected output from `$word`:

```
DAC_Datapath
JESD_RX
Overall_DV
RNM_model
tv5
1
2
3
path
RX
Overall_DV
M_model
tv15
1
2
3
```

Comment: Be more specific, what do you want to filter? The order of elements from `$word` before is not the same with the order of the expected output.

Comment: Does it has something to do with the `tv*5` elements which needs to remain and the other ones to be filtered?

Comment: Yes here tv5 (i.e the digit 5 is bigger compared to other tv).So other rows remain to be same where ever tv range starts at that range it should compare with other tv and print the greatest one.Like wise after few more rows we will find tv11..tv15.At point it should print tv15.For your knowledge the other rows should not be affected while doing for tv* @JohnDoe

Comment: $word prints any characters but we should consider only with tv* and should bring like expected output .@JohnDoe

Comment: For your information in my expected output i had shown how the tv should be displayed.The main part is to work with tv* @JohnDoe

Comment: FYI, please provide this kind of informations when you are posting the question, otherwise this might get you some downvotes :)

Comment: The `tv*` s are always ordered ascending?

Comment: Those values may shuffle it wont be in ascending order always @JohnDoe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the most efficient or correct way to do it, but it ain't stupid if it works, right? (not really).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# read the $word, you will ignore this part since you already have it
my $word = "";
while( <DATA>)
{
    $word .= $_;
}

# split each line from $word and store the lines in an array
my @lines = split /\n/, $word;

# the initial value is 0
my $max_value = 0;

# iterate over the lines
for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar (@lines); $i++)
{
    # if the current line matches the pattern tv1234*
    if ( $lines[$i] =~ /tv(\d*)/)
    {
        # $max_value will store the 1234*
        $max_value = int($1);
        # get the index of the next line
        my $j = $i+1;

        # if the next element matches the pattern tv1234*
        if ( $lines[$j] =~ /tv(\d*)/)
        {
            # check if the value if the value from the next line is 
            # lower than the max value
            if ( int($1) < $max_value)
            {
                # if it is remove the next line
                splice(@lines, $j, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                # max value is the value of the next line
                $max_value = int ($1);
                # otherwise remove the current one
                splice ( @lines, $i, 1);
                # since we delete the current index, decrement it to don't skip
                $i--;
            }
        }
        # we finished the block of tv*s so we reset the max value
        else
        {
            $max_value = 0;
        }
    }
}

# recompute the initial $word with the filtered lines
my $word = join ("\n", @lines);
print $word;

__DATA__
DAC_Datapath
JESD_RX
Overall_DV
RNM_model
tv1
tv2
tv3
tv4
tv5
1
2
3
path
RX
Overall_DV
M_model
tv11
tv12
tv13
tv14
tv15
1
2
3
```

Comment: i face error when i using with filehandle .I had posted same altered code with the question .@John Doe

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution code.
Just a suggestion, please try to elaborate question, so that person can easily understand.

Code:

```
use strict;

my @in = qw/DAC_Datapath JESD_RX Overall_DV RNM_model tv1 tv2 tv3 tv4 tv5 1 2 3 path RX Overall_DV M_model tv11 tv12 tv13 tv14 tv15 1 2 3/;

print "Input is :\n" . join("\n", @in) . "\n\n" . '-'x40 . "\n\n";

my @out;
my @tv;
my $biggerTV;

foreach my $data (@in) {
    if($data =~ /^tv/i){
        push(@tv, $data);       
    }
    else{
        if(@tv){
            # find bigger tv now
            foreach my $tv (@tv){
                my $tvNum = $tv; $tvNum =~ s/tv//i;
                my $biggerTVNum = $biggerTV; $biggerTVNum =~ s/tv//i;
                $biggerTV=$tv if($tvNum > $biggerTVNum);
                # print "$biggerTV\n";
            }
            push(@out,$biggerTV);
            @tv = (); # empty TV array
            $biggerTV = "";
        }
        push(@out,$data);
    }
}

print "Output is :\n" . join("\n", @out);
```

Code Execution output:

`Input is :`

```
DAC_Datapath
JESD_RX
Overall_DV
RNM_model
tv1
tv2
tv3
tv4
tv5
1
2
3
path
RX
Overall_DV
M_model
tv11
tv12
tv13
tv14
tv15
1
2
3
```

`Output is :`

```
DAC_Datapath
JESD_RX
Overall_DV
RNM_model
tv5
1
2
3
path
RX
Overall_DV
M_model
tv15
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my reference link which i had revamped the code .
[code copy and utilization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653081/how-to-change-the-regular-expression-for-word-using-perl)

My code:

```
if(-f $outfile)

{

my $word = "";
$word=~s/("\S+|\S+|")\s*/$1/g;
open my $word1,'<',$word or die "error";
while( <$word1>)
{
    $word .= $_;
}
close $word1;

# split each line from $word and store the lines in an array
my @lines = split /\n/, $word;

# the initial value is 0
my $max_value = 0;

# iterate over the lines
for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar (@lines); $i++)
{
    # if the current line matches the pattern tv1234*
    if ( $lines[$i] =~ /tv(\d*)/)
    {
        # $max_value will store the 1234*
        $max_value = int($1);
        # get the index of the next line
        my $j = $i+1;

        # if the next element matches the pattern tv1234*
        if ( $lines[$j] =~ /tv(\d*)/)
        {
            # check if the value if the value from the next line is 
            # lower than the max value
            if ( int($1) < $max_value)
            {
                # if it is remove the next line
                splice(@lines, $j, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                # max value is the value of the next line
                $max_value = int ($1);
                # otherwise remove the current one
                splice ( @lines, $i, 1);
                # since we delete the current index, decrement it to don't skip
                $i--;
            }
        }
        # we finished the block of tv*s so we reset the max value
        else
        {
            $max_value = 0;
        }
    }
}

# recompute the initial $word with the filtered lines
my $word = join ("\n", @lines);
print $word;
```

}

Error:

error at ./generate_dcms_html.pl line 4,

Comment: `open my $word1,'<',$word or die "error";` look from where you are reading -_-

Comment: actually your flow of code will work properly but the thing is i had used regular expression in my $word which i had showed up in my question.Now the same $word should read inside the while loop.Now passing $word directly into while loop it fails to read the $word variable contents .I need some help in that part .How can i pass regular expression result variable into while loop inside yuor same code .@JohnDoe

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
use warnings;
use strict;
chomp(my @ar = <DATA>);
my $f = 0;
my @dumy;
my @vr;
foreach (@ar)
{
    (/(^\d+$|\D+$)/)?"@{[push(@vr,$_) and $f=0]}":push(@dumy,$_) and $f = 1;
    if(($f == 0) && @dumy)
    {
        push(@vr,(sort{$b cmp $a} @dumy)[0]);
        ($vr[-1],$vr[-2]) = ($vr[-2],$vr[-1]);
        @dumy = ();
    }

}

print join "\n",@vr,"\n";


__DATA__
DAC_Datapath
JESD_RX
Overall_DV
RNM_model
tv1
tv2
tv3
tv4
tv5
1
2
3
path
RX
Overall_DV
M_model
tv11
tv12
tv13
tv14
tv15
1
2
3
```

Comment: The user as you may have ( or not) observed is kinda new to Perl ( can't even read properly from the file). This is close enough to obusfucated code. So no offence, but without some comments ... your code is not really helpfull.